# Determining the number of user dropping after an occurence

Tags: r

I am a database that looks like this:

```
userId              Screen         Platform       Version
01                  first          IOS            1.0.1
01                  main           IOS            1.0.1
02                  first          Android        1.0.2
03                  first          IOS            1.0.2
03                  main           IOS            1.0.2
03                  detail         IOS            1.0.2
```

Basically I look like to know how many people are "dropping" after the first screen, so my idea was to create a new column where it tells the number of screen the user went through by userId,
Ideal database would look like this:

```
userId              DifferentScreen        Platform      Version
01                  2                     IOS            1.0.1
02                  1                     Android        1.0.2
03                  3                     IOS            1.0.2
```

I have tried :

```
setDT(database)[order(userId) ,. (DifferentScreen = uniqueN(Screen), Version = Version[1L], Platform = Platform[1L], by = userId)]
```

But it doesn't work, the problem I have identified: it doesn't group by userId as the number of column stays the same, I use the command uniqueN because I haven't found a command that just do .N().

Comment: Thanks for the question. We can try to work with this but it's always highly preferable for you to `dput` the data or otherwise make it easily reproducible, so that we can work with your example data in R.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically there. There is only a minor issue regarding missing parentheses. Try:

```
dt[order(userId) ,. (DifferentScreen = uniqueN(Screen), Version = Version[1L], Platform = Platform[1L]), by = userId]

   userId DifferentScreen Version Platform
1:      1               2   1.0.1      IOS
2:      2               1   1.0.2  Android
3:      3               3   1.0.2      IOS
```

You need to close the parentheses BEFORE the `by = userID` not after. This way `data.table` reads the `by=...` as a by grouping instead of as a new variable called `by`. Currently, your output dataset is not grouping by anything, it thinks you want to create a variable called `by`.

You can see this in your old code's result:

```
dt[order(userId) ,. (DifferentScreen = uniqueN(Screen), Version = Version[1L], Platform = Platform[1L], by = userId)]

#See how this creates a variable "by"?
   DifferentScreen Version Platform by
1:               3   1.0.1      IOS  1
2:               3   1.0.1      IOS  1
3:               3   1.0.1      IOS  2
4:               3   1.0.1      IOS  3
5:               3   1.0.1      IOS  3
6:               3   1.0.1      IOS  3
```

**Data**:

```
dt <- structure(list(userId = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Screen = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("detail", "first", "main"), class = "factor"), 
    Platform = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Android", 
    "IOS"), class = "factor"), Version = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1.0.1", "1.0.2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("userId", 
"Screen", "Platform", "Version"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000250788>)
```